# update statement in sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

```
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;
    if (updateStmt == nil) 
    {
        const char *sql = " update PPM set amount = ? ";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.PPMdatabase, sql, -1,&updateStmt, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert (0,@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.PPMdatabase));
        }
    }
    sqlite3_bind_double (updateStmt,1, Val);
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
    {
        NSAssert(0,@"Error while updating.'%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(appDelegate.PPMdatabase));
    }
    sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
```

I get error: error while updating.unkown error

Comment: Can you reformat your question to make it readable? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between "PPMdatabaseTemp" and "PPMdatabase"? Can it be that you print an error code from a different database handle? Then, what is the exact error code output of sqlite3_step?

Comment: hey dat was by mistake its in PPMdatabase only

Answer (score 2):

You should be comparing `sqlite3_step()` against `SQLITE_OK` and then using the extended result codes for finer discrimination. Even the [documentation calls this scheme](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) "goofy".

The reason you are getting an "Unknown Error" is probably because you are calling `sqlite3_errmsg` when there was no error (that is, step() returned OK).

Comment: can you help me how to use where clause in the query?

Comment: And if i compare it against SQLITE_OK the program crashes.

Comment: I don't see a WHERE clause anywhere, and if changing a constant operand to the `!=` operator causes your program to crash, I can't be of any use at all. You might want to try the "teddy bear" method of debugging: Grab a teddy bear (or a brick, etc.) and explain to it what you are trying to do. You need practice explaining your problems and a brick is surprisingly good help at this. I'm not kidding.

Comment: hey thanks my problem of where clause is solved. And it works perfectly ok even with the sqlite3_step() being compared to the SQLIE_DONE. Thanks for all your help.